# How can I prevent the blocking between my deck joists from making noise under foot traffic?

Tags: framing, deck

Framing new deck 2x8x10 PT lumber. 
Used solid blocking bridging and just walking across mid span the blocks POP. 
All blocks were hand nailed with 12d common 
Galv.   When noticed popping went back and screwed with 4 inch epoxy coated screws 
Without much help ( decking is not installed yet )
Might try timber framing screws.

Comment: Why did you install blocking? That's not something I'd normally do for a deck since the decking tends to adequately share load with adjacent joists. At any rate, I can't imagine how 4" screws would leave much room for noise. Are they run in snug?

Comment: What is the span between joists?